# Как переписать значение jQuery?

Tags: javascript

Как переписать заначение JQuery, если переписывающее значение находится в другом файле?
Например, есть:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.tovar-slider').slick({
        dots: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        infinite: true,
   }); 
});
```

В другом файле, который подключается ниже

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.tovar-slider').slick({
        arrows: false,
    });
});
```

Как сделать, чтобы второе значение добавилось к первому, если они находятся в разных файлах?

Comment: А зачем такими глупостями заниматься?

Comment: Это можно сделать в php файле без всяких подключений js. Вам всего-то надо слайдер подключать, делайте это прям в файле внутри тега <script> и меняйте условиями что надо